# Creation of N deliveries from N Sales Orders in one BAPI_OUTB_DELIVERY_CREATE_SLS call?

Tags: sap-erp, bapi

I'm using  `BAPI_OUTB_DELIVERY_CREATE_SLS` to create deliveries from sales orders.

I'd like to call the `BAPI` 1 time with N delivery and have N sales order to improve the performance of the program but right now the `BAPI` gives me a delivery only for the first sales order.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Impossible.

This BAPI allows only N deliveries from different order **items** of a single order, not different orders.

From the documentation of `BAPI_OUTB_DELIVERY_CREATE_SLS` BAPI:

> A delivery is created **for a sales order or for individual sales order items**. A delivery split can mean that several deliveries are created.

Use it in a loop if you want process multiple orders.